# getting specific data from wordpress database table

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am trying to use WordPress logged in user id which should search `transaction_user_ID` in the table `wp_m_subscription_transaction`.

The table has a column called `transaction_user_ID` and another called `transaction_paypal_ID`.

logic:if user id == transaction user id then get transaction paypal id

which should be passed to the url  along with the user id email address 
and the execute the url to get the a code - this is my final output

How this can be achieved?

The code which I am developing is like this  which is  obviously incomplete & error for the getting and using the database query

```
<?php $user_id = get_current_user_id();
       $query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->;wp_m_subscription_transaction 

       if ($user_id ==$query) {
         <a href="http://primary.copyminder.com/cm_prodkey.php?DID=********&Password=*****&ProdCode=*******&NumRequired=1&TransNum=(GET THIS FROM DATABASE) &CustEmail=". $current_user->user_email .">Get ur Code</a>
   } 
else {
echo 'You are not logged in as user ';}?>
```

Comment: This code won't even run.  Do you have code that you can at least get to run? This is a fairly big mess.

Comment: no i dont have it,  i am still trying to get the code right to get the code atleast run but i am still learning from the tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since you need the email address as well, get all the current user's details, not just the id, using `wp_get_current_user()`.

Secondly, your query is wrong; you haven't closed the quotes, and have a stray semicolon.  If I've read it right, you need something like:

```
select transaction_paypal_ID
  from wp_m_subscription_transaction
 where transaction_user_ID = [the user's ID]
```

If you're only getting a single value in a query, you can retrieve it with `$wpdb->get_var()`

If the query doesn't return a row, it doesn't necessarily mean the user isn't logged in.  You can check if a user is logged in using `is_user_logged_in()`.

Something like this should work.  I haven't tested, and you'll have to build up the URL yourself.

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $paypal_id = $wpdb->get_var("select transaction_paypal_ID from wp_m_subscription_transaction where transaction_user_ID = " . (int) $user->ID);
    if ($paypal_id) {
        // Build up your URL here, with $paypal_id and $user->user_email
    }
    else {
        echo 'No transaction found for the current user';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'You are not logged in';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this works exactly as i wish , is their a way i can mask the url i build up as it will relieve some password in the url

Answer (score 2):

Try this query.

```
$query = "SELECT transaction_paypal_ID FROM wp_m_subscription_transaction where transaction_user_ID = ".$user_id;

$result = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query), ARRAY_A);
$transaction_paypal_ID = $result['transaction_paypal_ID'];
```

Answer (score 2):

This code comes without warrant, because you've not provided database structure, field names, or many other factors.

However, treated as pseudo-code, this will get you going in the right direction.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
// Global / bring in $wpdb, and the $table_prefix variables
global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
// Use $wpdb prepare to be sure the query is properly escaped
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $table_prefix . "m_subscription_transaction WHERE user_id = %d", $user_id);
// Turn on error reporting, so you can see if there's an issue with the query
$wpdb->show_errors();
// Execute the query
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
// Are there any records?  If so, that means the user ID matched
if ($results) {
    $row = $results[0];
    // Get the data from the row
    echo '<a href="http://primary.copyminder.com/cm_prodkey.php?DID=********&Password=*****&ProdCode=*******&NumRequired=1&TransNum=' . $row->TransNum . ' &CustEmail=". $current_user->user_email .">Get ur Code</a>';
} else {
    echo 'No records for this user.';
}
```