# WordPress Login (User ID) & Specific Table Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, wordpress

Thank you first of all for coming to try and help me solve an issue I am having with my current attempt to build a customer user system.

First of all, a brief explanation on the system I am trying to build might shed some light on the meaning behind my approach.

---

I am trying to build a system where the user can log into the website via the WordPress Login & Registration System, but then, based on their WordPress ID, they'll be given information related to that ID from another MySQL Table.

The reason for this is, we want to store specific data to users on another table, such as Weight, Height, Sex, and more.

The reason this needs to be in another table, is that an API from another service will directly put the data (and keep it up to date) in a specific table we will create.

---

The Code:

```
$servername = 'server';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if(! $conn )
   {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

$sql = 'SELECT pacientes.Id, wp_users.ID, pacientes.nombre
        FROM pacientes
        RIGHT JOIN wp_users
        ON pacientes.Id = wp_users.ID';

  mysql_select_db('database');

  $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

  if(! $retval )
  {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  echo "Fetched data successfully";
  mysql_close($conn);
```

Up until this point, everything seems to work as intended. I am given the all clear by all the die commands, and so I don't suspect there is any issue with finding, or locating the database, and tables I've mentioned.

The Code (Part 2)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  echo    "WordPress ID: {$row['ID']}  <br> ".
          "Patient Id: {$row['ID']}  <br> ".
          "Patient First Name: : {$row['nombre']} <br> ".
          "Patient Second Name : {$row['apellidos']} <br> ";
}
```

Now, this is echoing the data correctly. As you can see the Patient ID & WordPress ID are correctly associated with each other. The 4th user in the Patient Table is indeed Manuel.

You can see a quick screenshot here: https://gyazo.com/300af05da9afc8bcffa8f7efac628691

---

So my issue is with making this system only pull the data from the Patient Table, that is related to the ID of the current user, as chosen by the WordPress User ID.

I've looked at various sources that I will also link below, but none have so far produced what I am attempting to create.

Again; The intention here is that the user can log in using WordPress, and based off their WordPress ID co-inciding with an ID in the Patient Table, they should be shown their own specific data from the Patient Table, based on their ID's matching in both tables.

Current Research:

[Integrating wordpress authentication with an existing user database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922546/integrating-wordpress-authentication-with-an-existing-user-database)

[getting specific data from wordpress database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520693/getting-specific-data-from-wordpress-database-table)

[Get the data of specific user in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075424/get-the-data-of-specific-user-in-php)

---

I greatly appreciate any help, advice or guides you can provide me with. Thank you.

Comment: Any chance someone could lend a hand with this? I've been trying several other examples and none of them appear to work. Not sure if I've fundamentally misunderstood some concept of Php & MySQL or if I'm just making a minor mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a little more work I found the solution

---

Code (Database Connection & SQL Queries)

```
$servername = 'YourServer';
$username = 'YourUsername';
$password = 'YourPassword';

$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
if(! $conn )
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

 // Get the current User ID of the person logged into WordPress.
 $currentUser = get_current_user_id();

 $sql = 'SELECT wp_users.ID, sharedID, pacientes.nombre, pacientes.peso
        FROM pacientes
        RIGHT JOIN wp_users
        ON pacientes.Id = wp_users.ID';

    mysql_select_db('Sql918293_2');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
        {
           die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
        }

    echo "Fetched data successfully";
    mysql_close($conn);
```

---

Those code pulls all the relevant data from the databases, and joins them together so that you can use both tables, as long as they have a common ID. In this instance, the ID of the WordPress user needs to match the ID in the patient table.

Code (Echo the Data only to the relevant user)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  if ($row['Id'] == $currentUser)
  {
    echo
          "WordPress ID: {$row['ID']}  <br> ".
          "Patient Id: {$row['Id']}  <br> ".
          "Patient First Name: : {$row['nombre']} <br> ".
          "Patient Second Name : {$row['apellidos']} <br> ".
          "----------------------------------------<br>";
    }
}
```

The fix was actually really easy, and I have no idea why it pop into my head before. All I had to do was apply the $currentUser = get_current_user_ID(); to grab the ID from WordPress, and put it into a variable.

Then I did a simple If Statement to check against, and only to echo the information if the variable was correct.

```
if ($row['Id'] == $currentUser)
```

This basically checks against the ID (Patient ID) as seen above, and if it equals the same as the current user (As you're already logged into WordPress), then print the information.

I hope this helps everyone!